# Outlook plugin - how can I move an item to the spam folder

Tags: javascript, plugins, outlook

I'm developing an outlook plugin and I need to move an item to the spam folder once I've processed it. I have tried to use the Rest API but I don't have permission from the inbox to call to move the item.

I am calling getCallbackTokenAsync to get a token, and then calling the rest API with

```
  static async deleteEmail(id: string, token: string) {
    const url = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/${id}`;
    const response = await this.xhrRequest("DELETE", url, {}, token);
    return response;
  }
```

This returns an access denied error. My plugin has
`<Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>`
in the manifest so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

I believe I may need to launch my own web service which uses a client/secret to do this... can anybody help point me in the right direction?